# A bash script to repeat the same script action pressing return in terminal over and over again until i press q

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, command-line-interface

I want to make this script repeat the somescript.sh when I click return until I write q. I think I've gotten pretty close, but I can't make it set $actionLoop to 0 if it reads "q" what am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash

    $actionLoop = 1
    while [ ${actionLoop} 1 ]
    do
        echo "do another random review script?"
        sh /somescript.sh
        echo "Done.  Press q to quit."
        read response
        [ $response = "q" ] && $actionLoop = 0
    done
```

Comment: variable declaration/assignment must not start with $ and have no space between =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$actionLoop = 1
```

to

```
actionLoop=1
```

Similarly, this line

```
    [ $response = "q" ] && $actionLoop = 0
```

to

```
    [ $response = "q" ] && actionLoop=0
```

You can't use `$` when assigning a variable and you can't have whitespaces around the assignment either.

---

IMO, you don't need that variable at all. Use an infinite loop and break it when `q` is given.

```
while : ;
    do
        echo "do another random review script?"
        sh /somescript.sh
        echo "Done.  Press q to quit."
        read response
        [[ "$response" = "q" ]] && break
    done
```

I personally prefer bash built-in `[[` `]]` instead of `[` (test) command. Some prefer `[` for compatibility with older shells.